# Why does ctrl-shift-F12 (next error) start in middle of C# .cs file, in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to step through each compile error, beginning from top of file.
But <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> skips about half the errors, and select one near middle of them all, in my C# project.

And, if I set cursor at beginning of the .cs file, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>, it still goes to an error near the middle.

In my VB project, it works great -- selects the first one, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> again and it selects next... again and again until at beginning (first one) again. 
And if I go to top and do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>, it selects first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (Next Error) shortcut iterates through the items in the 'Error List' window of Visual Studio. The order that it will iterate through the items depends on how you have the error list sorted. If you would like it to go from the 'top' to 'bottom' of a certain file you could select 'Current Document' and sort by 'Line'.

[image]